# JQuery Autocomplete encoding in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, codeigniter, autocomplete

This works fine for English characters, but doesn't work for Arabic. I printed the query with "فف" for `$title`, i found strange characters in it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE agent_id = 1 AND type LIKE "owner" AND (firstName LIKE "%\%D9\%81\%D9\%81%" OR lastName LIKE "%\%D9\%81\%D9\%81%")
```

Here is my code:
controller:

```
public function getResultExtend($title) {     
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');        
    $result = $this->user->getOwners($user_id, $title);        
    foreach ($result as $user) {
      $user->userName = utf8_encode(stripslashes($user->userName));
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

View:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#search').keypress(function(e){
                if(e.which == 13)
                {   
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

                var searched = $('#search').val();
                var fullurl = $('#hiddenurl').val() + 'index.php/agent/getResultExtend/' + searched;

                $.getJSON(fullurl,function(result){
                    var elements = [];

                    $.each(result,function(i,val){
                        elements.push({ value: this.ID, label: this.firstName+' '+this.lastName});
                    });

                    $('#search').autocomplete({
                        source : elements,
                        select: function (event, ui) {
                           console.log(ui.item);
                        },
                        focus: function( event, ui ) {
                            $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.label );
                            return false;
                        },
                        select: function( event, ui ) {
                            $( "#search" ).val( ui.item.label );
                            $( "#owner_id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                            return false;
                        }
                    });    

                });
            });
        });
```

Model:

```
function getOwners($user_id, $title) {
    header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    //$title = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($title, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $title);
    $q = $this->db->query('SET NAMES utf8');
     $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users                     
                WHERE agent_id = ' . $user_id . ' AND type LIKE "owner" 
                AND (firstName LIKE "%'.$this->db->escape_like_str($title).'%"
                OR lastName LIKE "%'.$this->db->escape_like_str($title).'%")
                ');
    return $query->result();
}
```

My table collation is `utf8_unicode_ci` and the column is utf-8 also.
So, where is the problem?

Comment: After trying the query in PHPMyAdmin, i found that it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check rows in your application/config/database.php:

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Also try to add in your .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

OR directly to index.php add

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Comment: Done but nothing happened :(